# Reference each instance of an element on a document and set its display

Tags: jquery

I have 5 td elements with classes each in their own table nested in its own  tag; a series of tables. I'm trying to reference each of them and set the css display values. Seemingly simple enough. Instead only the first one gets affected no matter what looping structure I use.

Have tried:

```
 $('center').each(function(){  
     $( '.panoramaTable .panoramaTrHeader .tableQuestionHeader:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
 alert("counting");                 
});
```

Also various iterations of it with different class object set up. Always works on the first one and never on the subsequent ones. I set up a counter variable to see that each of the tables was getting accessed. Seems to be accessing all the tables, but not making the changes.

Comment: can u include the html code also. Its hard to give ans without that.

Comment: #tymeJV Yes, thanks, but as far as I know I should be targeting every .panoramaTable class, .panoramaTrHeader .tableQuestionHeader:eq(2) element.

Comment: @tymeJV it seems to me i'm targeting each of the elements inside a new  <center> tag, which is what I wanted to do.

Comment: the code looks like this. I can't copy and paste, because it's dynamically generated. It would like like XSL.

Comment: <center>
    <br/> 
        <table>
            <td>
            <td>
            <div>
                <table>
                     <tbody>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                             <td class=".tableQuestionHeader">
                             <td class=".tableQuestionHeader"> 
                             <td class=".tableQuestionHeader">

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this lay in setting the right panoramaTable class table for each iteration of a center element. As it turns out, the center element itself doesn't focus as an anchor of any type in the DOM, it just works like a counter. :)